# AWK using 10 000 input files: Add columns and merge to 1 file without redundant headers

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed, terminal

I have about 1 week's experience with AWK, so please bear with me.

Using Terminal on Mac, I am trying to consolidate a dataset that is scattered across approx. 10000 files. Each file has between 0 and a couple of thousand lines.

Each file contains various columns, and the columns are not always the identical, nor in the same order. But all files seem to have:

```
Timestamp,UserId
2016-01-08 15:57:49,<alphanumeric string>
```

Occasionally a file:

- is empty
- contains headers, but no lines of data

...and therefore does not need to be added to the consolidated destination file.

The folder name (without path) contains information about what action was taken on the timestamps in the file. The file name contains information about what caused the action.

Therefore I would like to add columns with folder name (without path) and file name (without extension) respectively, and have one consolidated file with the below columns (in addition to the bulk of other columns):

```
Timestamp,UserId,Action,Cause
2016-01-08 15:57:49,<alphanumeric string>,<folder name>,<file name>
```

In the case of the other columns, if there happens to be a match (a column exists in the source file) then its value is added to destination file. If there is no match (i.e. column does not exist in source file) then value in destination file is set to either null or as an empty string.

So far, I have figured out that...

```
awk '{if(NR!=1){print}}' source.csv >> destination.csv
```

...will print data, excluding header, from source to destination.

Also, I have figured out that...

```
awk '{print FILENAME ",", $0}' source.csv >destination.csv
```

...will add filename to beginning of all lines and print to destination file.

(Although it adds a whitespace, which I dont want, since the data is comma-separated, as well as adding the file extension to the record).

Similarly...

```
'{print $NF}'
```

can be used to print folder name.

**Question:**
How can the AWK commands above be modified to

- Take into consideration matching/non-matching columns, and either copy values from source to destination or set values to null as needed?
- Traverse through folders and perform these actions on all files in the folders, preferably without:

  - adding whitespaces,
  - without adding file extension from filename

Thanks!

...Hope that wasn't (too) unclear.

Comment: too broad without a small set of sample data that covers all cases you intend to handle, as well as sample data for cases that should be skipped, and cases that should be passed thru without processing. Please spend some time working thru the `awk` tutorial at http://grymoire.com/Unix/awk.html and then post a new Q that is a little more focused. With 10000+ files, you'll most likely need to use either `xargs` or `parallel`, but get your code to work for <10 files before you worry about 10000.

Comment: AND StackOverflow is about helping people fix their programming code. We need to see some code, in order to help, else your Q is off-topic for StackOverflow. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter: Thanks for the quick reply. If I understand you correctly, a solution would be to 1) write foo.awk that solves the problem(s) for one file 2) write a bash script in which a) `xargs` is used to store all filenames with path and b) foo.awk is used on all files in `xargs`. If that's the case, it does help setting the general direction, as I was trying to do everything in one foo.awk.

Comment: that's about right. The typical usage with `xargs` is `find /root/path/to_files_of_interest -name '*.txt| xargs foo.awk`   There are many `[bash] xargs` questions here. The `xarg` example I've included assumes files without spaces in the filename. Otherwise there is an extra bit of syntax required.  Good luck.